# How to capture redirect url's in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control, redirect

I want to implement a authentication process and I need to get some token value from the query parameter of a redirection URL. That redirection URL is having 302 status in fiddler. But I am not able to get that URL in WebBrowser navigating or any other event, directly I am getting the next URL which is following redirection URL. Please let me know on how to capture redirect URL while using WebBrowser Control.

Thanks.